# Java classpath library(jar)

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I don't know how to compile and run Java program with another library.
I read many threads about this, but none of them helped. Most of them just talking around it and stuff instead of providing a decent example. Although trying for the past week, I couldn't make it to work.

Imagine I have the following structure (~ is home directory):

- ~/Graph.java
- ~/jmathplot.jar

Graph.java starts with:

```
import org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel;

public class Graph { ... }
```

It (org.math.plot) corresponds to .jar structure. So from what I read (if I run this from ~ directory):

```
javac -classpath ./jmathplot.jar Graph.java
```

this should work. But it doesn't. It just generates bunch of .class files from jmathplot.jar and when trying to run it I get NoClassDefFoundError. If I extract "org" folder from jmathplot.jar and put it next to Graph.java it works flawlessly (which is expected); you don't even need to specify classpath.

I think of classpath as a guidance to JVM where to look for files. Specifying jmathplot.jar instructs JVM to look for /org/math/plot structure in jmathplot.jar.

Where am I wrong? Could someone provide me a correct way to compile and run this Graph.java? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

after you get all your `.class` files compile into `/path/to/some/dir`, you can run it with:

```
java -cp "~/jmathplot.jar;/path/to/some/dir/*" com.package.YourMainClass
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that "/path/to/some/dir/*".

Comment: I meant, that when you compiled your `Graph.java`, you generated a bunch of `.class` files, as you said it yourself, which were spawned into your current working directory. so that directory should be on the classpath, so java can know where to find those compiled `.class` files.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans...) which can do the work for you?

Comment: Well I wrote it in Eclipse and it worked, but I need to know how to do it in general.

Comment: javac -cp pathToYourJarFile.jar Graph.java

Answer (score 0):

Try with a forward slash and without the dot. Like this:
`javac -cp \jmathplot.jar Graph.java`